# Mathematically divide two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to calculate the return rate % from arrays.

```
$returnRate = array(106);
$netSales =  array(5472);
```

The formula to calculate the Return Rate %  `$returnRate / ($netSales + $returnRate );` = returnRatePercentage

I figure out a way to add two arrays

```
$c = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $netSales, $returnRate);
```

But I cant seem to find a way to take divide $returnRate by $c.

any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to have an array division you can use this code.

```
$returnRate = array(106);
$netSales =  array(5472);
$c = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $netSales, $returnRate);

$results =  array_map('division', $returnRate, $c);

function division($a, $b)
{
    return $a / $b;
}
```

The result will be in `$result`

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate an average simply with `sum/count`.

```
$returnrate = array_sum($array) / $count($array);
```

This will work for any array `[1,2,3,..]`, etc..

There are possibly some issues with how you're storing data in your arrays, though.  `$netSales = array(5472);`  This is saying that there is one net sale of a weight of `5472`, not that there were 5,472 net sales.

For the $returnrate above to be correct, you'll need an array like, `[10, 20, 30,]`, in which the values being averaged are available, etc..

Comment: Well, the data is coming from an array of info.  Before I calculate, I have to remapped the data to a key.  Once I have the data mapped, I am looping through the results.   the arrays do have more numbers in it, but when looping through them, their will always be one set per key

Comment: Hi, Chris m -- That does seem like an involved procedure.  Is there a reason why the above code won't work?  Simplicity is beauty.

Comment: Thank you for your help HoldOffHunger, I left one big piece out.   I am not trying to calculate the return rate.  I am trying to calculate the ReturnRate%.   which uses the formula I listed above.  I edited my original question.

Comment: @Chrism: Ah, I see!  I'll try to update my answer, but...  maybe you can clarify a bit more?  You say you have the "return rate", but you want to calculate "return rate percentage."  To my understanding, these are the same thing?  Do you mean, you have the returned-count, and then you need to calculate the returned rate?  Just trying to understand better, thanks.

Comment: no, the returnRate is a separate formula.   What we are using to calculate the returnRate % is the one listed.